# rich text editor properties

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce, rich-text-editor

In the following RTE I have to reduce the width but doing this means removing some of the features like remove bold,underline options,........

**Is there any way to reduce the width without removing the buttons?**

i.e, the buttons should appear in a small kind of dropdown arrow.

```
     function MYRTE()
     {

     theme : "advanced",
     theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,|,bold,italic,underline,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
     theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,search,replace,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
     theme_advanced_buttons3 : 


      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the heigth is no issue you could use a[n additional button column as specified here](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/theme_advanced_buttons_1_n) and place some of the other columns buttons there.

Answer (score 1):

Use Something like FireBug in firefox or developer tools of Chrome or what ever browser you use, find the button id and class then edit the CSS file coming with your editor or use jquery to style them.

or if you can put and online demo so i can help you with that.